# How to get,multiple GET request params from angular to nodejs/Express js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, get

I want to retrieve various request params in express sent to me by angular but I keep on getting 404 error:
Code angular controller:

```
var config = {
     params: { userid: "userffvfid ",
                pass:"abcd"
            }};

$http.get('/erai',config).success(function(response) {
    console.log("I got the data I requested");
    $scope.therapist_list = response; });
```

Node js/Express js code:

```
app.get('/erai',function(req,res){
    console.log("got request");
    console.log(req.params.userid);
    console.log(req.params.pass);
    res.send("hello");
});
```

How do i access the params properly and respond to it properly w/o getting 404 error?

Comment: Open Chrome console, log XHR requests and check if You are sending correct req.
Open the API in new tab/curl/wget and check if node server is responding.
Check in server logs Which API is being called.
When in doubt, log everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When making a get request like that any payload will be appended in the url.

So the final request url will be something like

```
http://www.example.com?user=John&password=Doe
```

To access those variables in express use the `req.query` object

in your case

```
var userid = req.query.userid
var pass = req.query.pass
```

If you go the POST way your data will be in the payload
You will have to use a body parser middleware and then access the data with
`req.body`

Comment: I dint get the details what changes should I make in my express controller

Comment: make the config object just `var config = {userid: 'id, pass: 'pass'}` and then in your controller access them with `req.query.userid` and `req.query.pass`